# Styles not working properly in <td>

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using the below HTML in JSP and it is loading using `window.open()` function. It is working properly in original page but it is not loading properly when window.open in IE7. Any idea please?

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed;">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" class="tableinnercontent" width="60%" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
            ${dynamic text here}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Please pay attention to the post preview. **It's displayed right under where you typed your post**, which makes me wonder why you didn't see that your HTML isn't visible

Comment: How exactly is it not working "properly" in IE? Does it look wrong? Not show at all? Wrong content?

Comment: @Juhana thank you.that is why I'm wondering. but it is not working. :(

Comment: wat style is not applying in IE?

Comment: @Praveen, style="word-wrap: break-word; is not applying. Line not breaking as expecting in <td>

Answer (score 0):

As word-wrap is a CSS3 property, it is only supported by IE9 and higher. For IE8 try

```
          word-wrap: break-word;
        -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
```

**Update**

It seems that even if you use -ms-word-wrap in IE7, it defaults the white-space: nowrap; which then overrides the word-wrap property.

Once again a IE hack is required. Try adding this for IE7.

```
white-space: normal;
```